# Error when trying to post using $resource

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following which calls the entityService.postEntity function:

```
   entityService.postEntity($scope.entityType, formData)
   .then(function (result) {
      $scope.grid.data.push(result);
   }, function (result) {
      alert("Error: " + result);
   })
```

Here's my entity resource and the postEntity function:

```
   var EntityResource = $resource('/api/:entityType', {}, {
      postEntity: { url: '/api/:entityType/', method: 'POST' },
   });

   postEntity: function (entityType, entity) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      EntityResource.postEntity({ entityType: entityType }, entity,
         function (resp) {
               deferred.resolve(resp);
         }, function (resp) {
               deferred.reject(resp.data.exceptionMessage);
         });
         return deferred.promise;
   },
```

The above works for me.

**Now** I tried to replace this with:

```
 var entityResource = $resource('/api/' + $scope.entityType + '/');
 entityResource.save({}, formData)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       var a = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       var b = data;
    });
```

It's giving me the error:

```
Object #<b> has no method 'success'
```

Can someone give me advice on what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$resource returns a $then. Use it like this:

```
var myThing = $resource(...);
var myResult = myThing.save({}, formData);
myResult.$then(function(data){}, function(data){});
//             success           failure
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it does not seem to go to the .$then. I put a breakpoint on everything and it skips it completely. Is it correct with a $ before then? Also should I be using .save((), formData) where formData is my object ?

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the wrong info. I edited my code above. It should work now. Your save call returns a promise, which when resolved should go through the $then blocks.